# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_csv'

Tags: python, file, export-to-csv

I have an output which type of is str. I want to write it a file but it shows this error.

I tried `write` and `to_excel` commands but it give same error.

Error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-b62c7c6bb434> in <module>
  7         with open(name) as f:
  8             data = f.read().replace("\n", " ")
----> 9      data.to_csv("C:\\Users\\frknk\\OneDrive\\Masaüstü\\enron6\\maaail.txt")
 10             print(data)
 11     except IOError as exc:

 AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_csv'
```

My code:

```
import glob
import errno
path =r'C:\Users\frknk\OneDrive\Masaüstü\enron6\emails\*.txt'
files = glob.glob(path)
for name in files:
    try:
        with open(name) as f:
            data = f.read().replace("\n", " ")
            data.to_csv("C:\\Users\\frknk\\OneDrive\\Masaüstü\\enron6\\maaail.txt")
            print(data)
    except IOError as exc:
        if exc.errno != errno.EISDIR:
            raise
```

Comment: The return of f.read() is a simple python str (string) type. Strings have not to_csv() function,

Comment: But I have to write it to a file. How can i do that?

Comment: what does the file you're reading look like?

Comment: It is include email with enter characters. So, it is string. I can share image if you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the first answer don't save all your output it is because it overwrites your file everytime.

do:

```
list = []
for name in files:
    list.append(name.strip())
with open("file.csv", "w") as file:
    for element in list:      
        file.write(element + "\n")
```

this should fix your problem!

Comment: With this code your save your names in a list and put this list element for element in your file

Comment: This code's output is location of my txt files.C:\Users\frknk\OneDrive\Masaüstü\enron6\emails\0001.2000-06-06.lokay.ham.txt
0 C:\Users\frknk\OneDrive\Masaüstü\enron6\emails...
1 C:\Users\frknk\OneDrive\Masaüstü\enron6\emails...

Answer (score 2):

there is no `to_csv()` method for strings.

Try doing:

```
with open("file.csv","w") as file:
    file.write(data + "\n")
```

Comment: OK, I write your code but file that we created is not include my all output.